# MS Powerpoint 2016 disable navigation to next slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want a Powerpoint presentation to only navigate to the next page or previous page when i click specific buttons (custom action buttons that I have created). Apart from this, i do not want the slide to transition to the next page even though all the animations have been completed on this page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Slide Show Setup to put the presentation in Kiosk mode.